# Excel VBA how to get address delta of cell(s) not used between two separate non-congruent adjoining cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm going to struggle in finding a way to describe what I'm trying to accomplish...

I have a matrix of data that I'm updating by adding 'n' number of rows based on a unique key (date) from another worksheet. I've already implemented the copying of the key over to the matrix. Now, I want to copy the last used row, which contains formulas, over to the empty rows associated with updated 'n' key(s).

So, my question is, how do I use VBA to determine the number of rows that are empty between what was last used and what I just pasted?

I can brute force it IE I can get the address of the row I just copied data to and separate the letter from the number coordinate. Do the same for the last used row of the data that was last entered, subtract the numbers and get my delta. However, that seems to really be brute forcing that is quite unnecessary.

```
 Date   |  col1  |  col2  |  col3  |  col4  |  col5  |  Total  |
```

---

```
 2-Jan  |   0    |    1   |    1   |    0   |    0   |    2    |
 3-Jan  |   2    |    0   |    4   |    1   |    0   |    7    |
 5-Jan  |   0    |    0   |    0   |    1   |    1   |    2    |
 8-Jan  |   X
10-Jan  |
13-Jan  |   Y
```

So looking at the matrix above, Jan 8 through Jan 13 are new inserts. I'm trying to determine the cells from X to Y. Once I've figured that out, I will paste the formulas that are in col1-total into the rows correlating with X through Y.

Comment: It seems to me it should be pretty simple, but maybe I'm missing something... You know what row you started with (`8-Jan`) when you started inserting, and you know how many rows you inserted (because you did so). All you need is the column for the `Total`, and you can use a range to copy the formula. For instance, if `Date` is `A1`, and `Total` is `G1`, you know when inserting the new rows that you're starting with `A5` and adding 3 rows, so you'll need to copy the formula from `G4` into `G5..G7`. There isn't any calculation involved, other than adding the number of rows added to starting row.

Comment: The row I know I started with is not 8-Jan but 5-Jan. There's a part I didn't mention because I didn't think it was really important to be known. The way the dates get added is not as straight forward as one would think. They get added from a source where there are multiple dates of the same day. When they get copied into this table, they get sorted and uniqued thus the source there could be twenty dates that then get truncated down to just three (in other words, the source could have three 8-Jans and six 10-Jans, etc). So I don't have a source of a # of new rows.

Comment: What I know is that I have the next empty row in col1 and the last used row in the date column. what I'm wondering is if there's a way to get a delta of the rows in between. Very poorly worded but hopefully my point is made?

Comment: I still don't understand the problem, I guess. Regardless of how many data points you use, you're still adding a finite number of rows. (If you "sort and unique" 30 or 3000 rows into 3, you're still adding 3 rows.) You have "the next empty row in col1 and the last used row in the date column", which seems to be all you need. If the "next empty row" is afterwards, your end row is that row - 1, and if you have the "last used row in the date column" after the insert, your ending row is that row - 1. I still don't see anything complicated here.

Comment: Ken, you're hitting it right on the spot! Let's say that the Date column is A and col1 is B and the rows are sequential from 1 starting from my column headers (so, 2-Jan is in row 2 and 13-Jan is in row 7).In my example above, I need to paste from B5 through B7. I know the number of addresses I need to paste into. What I don't know is the addresses! I can get my last row for B and get B5. I know my last row for A is A13. How do I translate that into a reference range for B13?? Do I just brute force it, remove the A from A13 and substitute that with B? I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a case of unknown unknowns.  You do not know what you do not know so you cannot ask.  We do not know what you do not know so do not tell.

The following code copies the last fully used row down over subsequent partly used rows.  Is this what you want?  It not, I hope this helps you clarify what you are after.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyDownOverNewRows()

  Dim ColLast As Integer
  Dim RngDest As Range
  Dim RngDestAddr As String
  Dim RngSrc As Range
  Dim RngSrcAddr As String
  Dim RowLastNew As Integer
  Dim RowLastOld As Integer

  With Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' Find last used column
    ColLast = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Find last used row in column A
    RowLastNew = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Find last used row in column B
    RowLastOld = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' The source range is the used area of the last full row
    ' but excluding column A
    RngSrcAddr = .Range(.Cells(RowLastOld, 2), _
                        .Cells(RowLastOld, ColLast)).Address

    ' Note the destination range includes the source range
    RngDestAddr = .Range(.Cells(RowLastOld, 2), _
                         .Cells(RowLastNew, ColLast)).Address

    ' Turn addresses into ranges
    Set RngSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(RngSrcAddr)
    Set RngDest = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(RngDestAddr)

    ' Fill the empty cells of the new rows from the last used row
    RngSrc.AutoFill Destination:=RngDest, Type:=xlFillSeries

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Having reread your question, I see "Date" is in column A, "col1" is in column B and so on.  In my code, I have used "B" and 2 where I should have used "C" and 3.  I will edit the answer if I am close to what you are after.

Comment: I did a little tweaking for my needs but the core of your code is exactly what I needed! Thank you!